# Pink/Blue Tint on Build Unity URP Post-Processing Bloom

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing, unity3d-shaders, urp

[pink build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7bOk.png)

[blue build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZzM0.png)

To preface this, we are using Unity 2019.3.0f6 and URP 7.2.1.

About 1/3 of the time we load a scene of our game (in build only) it is tinted pink with an orange strip at the top (pictured in “pink build”) or blue with a green strip at the top (pictured in “blue build”), until you enter the next scene. The other 2/3 of the time the screen is fine.

After looking through the shader compilation in the log, it appears that all of them are loading (nothing in the output changes between when pink/blue build happens and when it doesn’t). We then tried turning on and off different components on the camera just to isolate what might be causing the problem, (as the tint effect only happens below the Unity canvas so we thought it might be a problem with the camera/postprocessing).

We’ve narrowed the problem down to the Bloom Override on our Volume Profile on the Volume Component for Post Processing. Turning off the Bloom Override makes the problem go away in build, but we would like to keep the Bloom effect.

[the volume component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzxd0.png)

We’ve tried printing all of the values under the Bloom Override to see if there is an anomaly when it does the pink/blue v.s. when it doesn’t, but there is no difference. Literally nothing is different in our logs when it works and doesn’t work. The only thing we know for sure is that turning off the Bloom fixes the problem. If anybody has run into this, this is a desperate call for help, because we have absolutely no idea where to go from here.

[graphics settings screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXebT.png)

[graphics settings screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZNKo.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably, a rather individual problem. Since people with a similar problem have not yet answered, I will advise a general and simple solution. Create a new project, where there will be new settings **URP**, and already add a bloom effect in it. If everything works well and bloom works, then transfer these settings to your project (preferably create a backup, just in case).

If that doesn't help, then as an option, try changing other settings that appear before 2/3 of the game works well. Maybe it's some individual effects, that create a problem. Or according to my assumptions, in a vignette. It can also be in a sprite, that is drawn on top of the bloom (It is advisable to do all this, in a separate backup, so as not to accidentally break the project). Also, the problem may be in the camera, if the URP settings, sprites, etc. work well, and the bloom effect should not fail.

As a last resort, if this also does not work, then try to send a complaint to Unity support. There is a possibility, that this may be a mistake in the bloom effect itself.

Although I will assume that bloom removes the problem. But the error is in something else, and is displayed at the moment when the bloom effect is turned on. But since the URP is quite new, I do not exclude that this is a mistake of the bloom effect itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past, it fixed by changing LUT size to (16 or 32 or 64...), in urp asset settings/ post-processing.